# Setting background image in base template in Django

Tags: python, django

This is the structure of my Django project -

```
src/
    login_manager/
        migrations/
            ....
        __init__.py
        admin.py
        apps.py
        models.py
        views.py
        tests.py
        urls.py
    port/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
    static/
        admin/
            .....
    templates/
        login_manager/
            login.html
            .....
        __base.html
    media/
        image/
            containers.jpg
    manage.py
requirements.txt
```

Here, my project's name is **port**. And there is an app named **login_manager**, under this project. I am trying to add a background image for **__base.html** template. But for some reasons,it is failing.

Here is my **__base.html** -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>GPSL Inventory Management</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,
        initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <!--styles-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.5/yeti/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        body { 
         background: url('{{ MEDIA_URL }}image/containers.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
         -webkit-background-size: cover;
         -moz-background-size: cover;
         -o-background-size: cover;
         background-size: cover;
        }

        .panel-default {
          opacity: 0.9;
          margin-top:30px;
        }

        .form-group.last {
          margin-bottom:0px;
        }

        .container{
          margin: 0 auto;
        }
     </style>
    {% block extrahead %}
    {% endblock %}
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have registered my media url like following in **settings.py** -

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

How can i generate a background image in my parent template ?

**EDIT 1:** The image is static.

Comment: This background image, is it user uploaded or static?

Comment: @Wtower...it is static.

Comment: @ni8mr If the image is static, it makes more sense to keep it in `static` directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the background image is a static file, you should use the static url and not media.

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<style type="text/css">
        body { 
         background: url('{% static "image/containers.jpg" %}') no-repeat center center fixed; 
         -webkit-background-size: cover;
         -moz-background-size: cover;
         -o-background-size: cover;
         background-size: cover;
        }
</style>
```

You can read more about that in the relevant [Django docs: Managing static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/).

There is also a good reference on static files in the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial06/).

> Aside from the HTML generated by the server, web applications generally need to serve additional files — such as images, JavaScript, or CSS — necessary to render the complete web page. In Django, we refer to these files as “static files”.

A bit of extra care is required in order to properly setup static serving, but the documentation is very clear and there are also plenty of relevant questions on SO.

On the other hand, the media url concerns user-uploaded files as you can read in this [relevant documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/files/#managing-files).

Comment: So in summary, i should create a folder named image in the remaining static folder and put the background image in there ?   And than, follow your code?    I have tried it earlier, but i didn't get my image in the background.

Comment: Yes, mind that you need to properly setup static files.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to set static files now by following this - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files. I will come back after few minutes.

Comment: @Wtower.....Just another question, is it a good practice to create static folder in every app or i should keep an universal folder for all static files ?

Comment: @ni8mr welcome. It is a good practice to manage your static files in some sensible fashion. Only keep in mind that the static folder does not work like templates, so avoid overriding files with the same name in diferrent apps or you get nasty surprises with `collectstatic`.